# Software to measure quality of internet connection

Tags: internet, internet-connection, broadband, satellite, mobi

We are going to get a demo of satellite internet connection. Office is based in remote scottish highlands where internet speed is quite bad ( below 2 Mbps per line), a lot of outages due to weather etc. Whilst I am not entirely convinced that satellite is going to meet needs of our small business company proposed issuing equipment for testing purposes for few days.

I would like to avoid creating subjective measure of quality of this solution if this so I am thinking that I would like to run a tool that would measure speed, ping responses times, packets loss ( anything else that I need to measure ??? ) over period of running demo (few days) etc and return 'graphical' output of data.
Is there any tool that can do this ?

Comment: [This site](http://testmy.net/) would automate connection tests overtime

Comment: In order to get an accurate result you need to run any tests when te is no other internet activity - so this is probably best done manually. See www.speedtest.net and www.pingtest.net for popular testing sites.

Comment: Test antenna is going to connected to router and then I am planing to use dedicated machine on this line solely for this purpose.